# Why is blend mode not making each line equal in width?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

When applying a blend to two paths the lines in between them are not as wide.

This is what happens

[image]

To clarify, I want each line to be of equal length.

Comment: For me your question is not clear enouph. Can you please explain a little bit more what you need or want? For example add an (handwritten) image how it should look like? Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: @Kurt updated question. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: There is also `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...`, that you can use to make multiple duplicates of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the curves are connecting from opposite end to another (left end moving to right end and vice versa). Select the same point in each curve.